# What does bitwise-zeroing mean in structs construction?

Tags: c#, .net

I have been reading about **structs** in C#, I have found this topic interesting and significance respect (more natural for assignment, and stored in the heap) to classes, but I have a doubt respect to this paragraph in **C# 5.0 in a Nutshell**:

> A parameterless constructor that you can't override implicitly exists.
>   This performs a **bitwise-zeroing** of its fields

What it is means with **bitwise-zeroing**?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

***bitwise-zeroing*** means what it says: sets all the bits to zero.

The phrase is presumably used because when talking in general terms you do not know the type and therefore size) of the fields in question.

Answer (score 2):

> What it is means with bitwise-zeroing?

Basic English says it means making every bit zero.

This is important because it means it is a zero on the storage level, byte by byte - regardless whether the type itself has a logical connotation of a zero value (which it may well not have, or have multiple times). It means every new `struct` (and I can always declare it with new because this is an implicit constructor) gets all memory reset to 0.

In certain other languages this is not the case and you have manually reset the storage - or end up with whatever data was there before.